# Get package name of a annotated class within AnnotationProcessor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a class which I process with an AnnotationProcessor.
While in the process I have an instance of `javax.lang.model.element.Element` where I can i.e. get the name of the the annotated class by `.getSimpleName()`. What I know need is the packageName (*com.software.cool*) of the annotated class.

Any idea how to go through the API to receive it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely do not want to use `getQualifiedName`: it will produce surprising results in some cases. For example, it is impossible to distinguish last part of package name and parent class of inner classes: in "java.util.Map.Entry" is "Map" a part of package name or the name of containing class for `Entry`? What if instead of "java.util.Map.Entry" it is "a.b.c.d" (a typical case for Proguard-processed code)?

Likewise, for classes in default (unnamed) package there won't be anything before the dot…

With `getQualifiedName` your parsing code will be complex and unreliable. Generally speaking, when you have to use string representations of Element you are doing something wrong.

This is the proper pattern for getting package of `element`:

```
Element enclosing = element;
while (enclosing.getKind() != ElementKind.PACKAGE) {
    enclosing = enclosing.getEnclosingElement();
}
PackageElement packageElement = (PackageElement) enclosing;
```

This will correctly get package in *all* cases.

Answer (score 13):

The best way to go is to `ProcessingEnvironment.getElementUtils()` which has a very handy method called `getPackageOf`. 
In order to get `ProcessingEnviroment` you have to override `init` method within `AbstractProcessor` implementation.

```
public class DynamicServiceProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

private ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment;
private Elements elementUtils;

@Override
public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
    super.init(processingEnvironment);
    this.processingEnvironment = processingEnvironment;
    this.elementUtils = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils();
}

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> set, RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
    ...
    for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(DynamicService.class)) {
        PackageElement packageElement = processingEnvironment.getElementUtils().getPackageOf(element);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. There is a utility in the environment, so please make use of it.

Comment: This is obsolete as of Java 11, as `procesingEnv` is already available on `AbstractProcessor`.

Answer (score -1):

`element.getQualifierName()` actually had what I wanted!

thx to @Yogi

Answer (score -2):

You can use getPackage() method on class object i.e.

```
Element target;
Package pkg = target.getClass().getPackage();
String pkgName = pkg.getName();
```

For Further reading:
[getPackage Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getPackage())

Comment: Thanks for the pointout. Actually this yielded the `com.sun.tools.javac.tools` which is not what I needed. But thanks to you I found another solution